# Generating CSV files from Javascript with UTF-8 encoding and strings containing line breaks

Tags: html, excel, csv

I have a javascript program that can export HTML data tables to CSV.

This data is UTF-8 encoded so that it can contain a wide variety of character sets (English, French, Arabic, Japanese...).

The contents of particular cells in the data tables often contains line breaks

Before writing to a file I apply the following function to the contents of each table cell

```
function OutputFilter (Text)
{
Text = Text.replace (/<br>/g  , "\n"); // replace line breaks with new line
from = new RegExp ("<[^>]+>","g"); // replace any remaining HTML tags
to = "" ;
Text = Text.replace (from,to);
Text = Text.replace (/&quot;/g, '"'  ); // unescape all double quotes
Text = Text.replace (/&apos;/g, "'"  ); // unescape all single quotes
Text = Text.replace (/&lt;/g  , "<"  ); // unescape all <
Text = Text.replace (/&gt;/g  , ">"  ); // unescape all >
Text = Text.replace (/&amp;/g , "&"  ); // unescape all ampersands
var allQuotes = new RegExp ('"',"g"); //Text = Text.replace (/"/g, '""');
var twoQuotes = '""' ;
Text = Text.replace (allQuotes, twoQuotes); // duplicate all double quotes 
var commaInText   = Text.indexOf ("," ) != -1;
var quoteInText   = Text.indexOf ('"' ) != -1;
var newlineInText = Text.indexOf ("\n") != -1;
var commasRequired = commaInText || quoteInText || newlineInText ;
if (commasRequired) {return '"' + Text + '"' } else {return Text};
};
```

Now I am fairly sure I am heading in the correct direction because Mac Numbers reads the output CSVs correctly (or as I think they should be read).

However Excel for Mac behaves differently, as follows

1. If I double click to open the file, it recognises the converted line breaks (to "\n"), but does not recognise the UTF-8 encoding
2. If I import the data using the File/Import dialog, it recognises the UTF-8 encoding, but does not recognise the converted line breaks.

I am happy to just use MacOS Numbers but as half the world or more use Excel, I would like to be able to generate a CSV file that worked in Excel.

All help gratefully received
Thanks

Comment: Excel should recognize UTF-8 encoding if the CSV file is saved in UTF-8 with BOM encoding (UTF-8 Byte-Order-Mark; three bytes at the start of the file: 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF). For the newlines, use `"\r\n"` (CarriageReturn + LineFeed)

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks a lot Theo. I wasn't quite sure how to write the three extra bytes but another stack overflow answer said just prepend "\ufeff" to the output string, so I did.

Comment: Happy to hear it works for you. By the way, `\ufeff` stands for `UTF-16 (BE)` You can read about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)